# Debugging tips for CMake's failure to find Python (which is on $PATH)

Tags: python, cmake

I have a Python virtual environment (`venv` in the project dir) activated, so that `which python` points to the Python interpreter in this environment. The environment also has NumPy installed.

I also have a CMake build that should link a C library to this Python and the python is search for with

```
find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy)
```

However, CMake somehow manages not to find this interpreter and fails with an incredibly useful message:

```
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Python_EXECUTABLE Python_INCLUDE_DIRS
  Python_LIBRARIES Interpreter Development NumPy Development.Module
  Development.Embed)
```

Does anyone know any useful tips on how to debug this?
I even tried to set `-DPython3_EXECUTABLE=<abs-path-to-project-root/venv/bin/python` for CMake, but it does not help.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's the cause but CMake says missing `Python_EXECUTABLE` and you set `Python3_EXECUTABLE`... why?

Comment: If I understand the docs correctly, it says `Artifacts Specification¶

New in version 3.16.

To solve special cases, it is possible to specify directly the artifacts by setting the following variables:

Python3_EXECUTABLE

    The path to the interpreter.
`

Comment: Setting Python_EXECUTABLE did not work (probably, it just ignores it).